# EEA Faceted Navigation - How to create a new widget in our own product

Tags: plone

I created a new widget 'Slider' for EEA Faceted Navigation. 
It works fine but I made these changes directly in the original products.

For details, I added a new folder in `eea/facetednavigation/widgets` and modified `eea/facetednavigation/widgets/configure.zcml`.

I would like to move this new widget in my own product.

I've created some files and folder:

- my/product/widgets
- my/product/widgets/slider
- my/product/widgets/configure.zcml

and included my new package 'widgets' in the root zcml.

But it doesn't work:

```
Module eea.facetednavigation.browser.app.view, line 89, in get_sections
Module eea.facetednavigation.browser.app.view, line 96, in get_view_widgets
Module eea.facetednavigation.browser.app.view, line 111, in get_widgets
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered to contribute your widget right to the eea-package by contacting the authors? [btw: I hesiate to use this product because of a missing js-off-fallback and thereby breaking accessibility, allthough the UI is quite impressing.]

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at https://github.com/eea/eea.facetednavigation since I don't know what version you have.

It looks like that `<facet:widget />` directive (I assume you have in your my/products/widgets/configure.zcml file) attaches the widget to the widget registry *class*. They register all of their widgets, *then* instantiate the registry as a utility.

So, try re-instantiating that class by adding an overrides.zcml to your product at

my/product/overrides.zcml

with the following

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser">

  <configure package="eea.facetednavigation">
    <utility provides=".interfaces.IWidgetsInfo"
             factory=".widgets.WidgetsInfo" />
  </configure>

</configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** have to re-instantiate IWidgetsInfo :)

All you have to do is to register your widget:

`<faceted:widget factory=".widget.Widget" />`

See this faceted widget registered outside eea.facetednavigation namespace:

- https://svn.eionet.europa.eu/repositories/Zope/trunk/eea.dataservice/trunk/eea/dataservice/facetednavigation/lastversion/configure.zcml
- https://svn.eionet.europa.eu/repositories/Zope/trunk/eea.dataservice/trunk/eea/dataservice/facetednavigation/lastversion/